# How to add new fileds/values to line widgets in Barcode mobile view in Odoo14 EE?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Hi i am trying to add two new fields to the Barcode mobile view. I went through the default js code of odoo, but didn't find a way to add my custome fields to it.

Here is the default code
**stock_barcode/static/src/js/client_action/lines_widget.js**

```
init: function (parent, page, pageIndex, nbPages) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.page = page; #don't know where this argument page coming from in argument list.
    this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    this.nbPages = nbPages;
    this.mode = parent.mode;
    this.groups = parent.groups;
    this.model = parent.actionParams.model;
    this.show_entire_packs = parent.show_entire_packs;
    this.displayControlButtons = this.nbPages > 0 && parent._isControlButtonsEnabled();
    this.displayOptionalButtons = parent._isOptionalButtonsEnabled();
    this.isPickingRelated = parent._isPickingRelated();
    this.isImmediatePicking = parent.isImmediatePicking ? true : false;
    this.sourceLocations = parent.sourceLocations;
    this.destinationLocations = parent.destinationLocations;
    // detect if touchscreen (more complicated than one would expect due to browser differences...)
    this.istouchSupported = 'ontouchend' in document ||
                           'ontouchstart' in document ||
                           'ontouchstart' in window ||
                           navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ||
                           navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
},
```

In _renderLines function,

```
_renderLines: function () {
//Skipped some codes here
// Render and append the lines, if any.
    var $body = this.$el.filter('.o_barcode_lines');
    console.log('this model',this.model);
    if (this.page.lines.length) {
        var $lines = $(QWeb.render('stock_barcode_lines_template', {
            lines: this.getProductLines(this.page.lines),
            packageLines: this.getPackageLines(this.page.lines),
            model: this.model,
            groups: this.groups,
            isPickingRelated: this.isPickingRelated,
            istouchSupported: this.istouchSupported,
        }));
        $body.prepend($lines);
        for (const line of $lines) {
            if (line.dataset) {
                this._updateIncrementButtons($(line));
            }
        }
        $lines.on('click', '.o_edit', this._onClickEditLine.bind(this));
        $lines.on('click', '.o_package_content', this._onClickTruckLine.bind(this));
    }
```

In the above code, you can see this.page.lines field, i need to add my custom two more fields.
Actually it's dead-end for me.
Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried to change/extend the QWeb template "stock_barcode_lines_template"? Because seems that one is rendered on that part.